# How to change value of several submit buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How I can rename all **submit** buttons when I'm clicking on it?

I need script, which will change **submit** button's value to smth like "Loading..." for all buttons.

I need full jQuery or Javascript script.

Comment: If you need script, you write script.

Comment: We help you with script if you make script first

Comment: Run a javascript countdown timer, at different intervals change the value of the buttons using document.getElementByID() until the timer finishes counting down.

Comment: You try, we help. That's how this works.

Comment: We don't provide code writing facility. We just gonna help you if you have done something, and messed between some code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7EJGd/2/

HTML:

```
<input type="submit"/>
<input type="submit"/>
<input type="submit"/>
<input type="submit"/>
<input type="submit"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
var btns, i, i2;

btns = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='submit']");

for (i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
     btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
       for (i2 = 0; i2 < btns.length; i2++) {
           btns[i2].value = "loading...";
       }            
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by changing button text:-

```
 <body onload="test()">
    <script>
        function test(){
           $('button').click(function(e){
               console.log('in click');
               var currentVal = $(e.currentTarget).text();
               $(e.currentTarget).text("Loading...");
               //Do sutuff
               //change button text
               //$(e.currentTarget).text(currentVal);
           });

        }
    </script>
    <button>Send</button>
</body>
```